# java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space despite having sufficient memory on Spark 2

Tags: apache-spark

I am running a Spark 2.1.1 job on an Azure VM (local mode), 16 core, 55 GB RAM.

I initialize with this command:

```
./spark-2.1.1-bin-hadoop2.6/bin/spark-shell --driver-memory 45G --packages "io.archivesunleashed:aut:0.12.1"
```

And run the following script on data:

```
import io.archivesunleashed.spark.matchbox.{ExtractDomain, ExtractLinks, RemoveHTML, RecordLoader, WriteGEXF}
import io.archivesunleashed.spark.rdd.RecordRDD._
val r = RecordLoader.loadArchives("/data2/toronto-mayor/*.gz", sc).keepValidPages().map(r => ExtractDomain(r.getUrl)).countItems().saveAsTextFile("/data2/toronto-mayor-data/all-domains")
```

The data is relatively small (290GB) but consists of 292 files, ranging in size from 7GB to 38KB. Average size around 1GB. Swap of 100GB is available on this machine, and I've monitored `htop` while executing and there are no memory spikes above 45GB and no swap usage. It all seems to be working well, and then tumbles down...

It crashes with the following error:

```
ERROR Executor - Exception in task 13.0 in stage 0.0 (TID 13)
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
        at java.util.Arrays.copyOf(Arrays.java:3332)
        at java.lang.StringCoding.safeTrim(StringCoding.java:89)
        at java.lang.StringCoding.access$100(StringCoding.java:50)
        at java.lang.StringCoding$StringDecoder.decode(StringCoding.java:154)
        at java.lang.StringCoding.decode(StringCoding.java:193)
        at java.lang.StringCoding.decode(StringCoding.java:254)
        at java.lang.String.<init>(String.java:546)
        at java.lang.String.<init>(String.java:566)
        at io.archivesunleashed.data.WarcRecordUtils.getWarcResponseMimeType(WarcRecordUtils.java:102)
        at io.archivesunleashed.spark.archive.io.ArchiveRecord.<init>(ArchiveRecord.scala:74)
        at io.archivesunleashed.spark.matchbox.RecordLoader$$anonfun$2.apply(RecordLoader.scala:37)
        at io.archivesunleashed.spark.matchbox.RecordLoader$$anonfun$2.apply(RecordLoader.scala:37)
        at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.next(Iterator.scala:409)
        at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$13.hasNext(Iterator.scala:462)
        at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$13.hasNext(Iterator.scala:461)
        at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.hasNext(Iterator.scala:408)
        at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.hasNext(Iterator.scala:408)
        at org.apache.spark.util.collection.ExternalSorter.insertAll(ExternalSorter.scala:191)
        at org.apache.spark.shuffle.sort.SortShuffleWriter.write(SortShuffleWriter.scala:63)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ShuffleMapTask.runTask(ShuffleMapTask.scala:96)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ShuffleMapTask.runTask(ShuffleMapTask.scala:53)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:99)
        at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:322)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

Many of the other discussions on this site involve either cluster mode, or setting `--driver-memory`. Any help appreciated.

#### Attempts so far (updated)

```
./spark-2.1.1-bin-hadoop2.6/bin/spark-shell --driver-memory 45G --packages "io.archivesunleashed:aut:0.12.1"
./spark-2.1.1-bin-hadoop2.6/bin/spark-shell --conf spark.memory.fraction=0.4 --driver-memory 45G --packages "io.archivesunleashed:aut:0.12.1"
./spark-2.1.1-bin-hadoop2.6/bin/spark-shell --conf spark.memory.fraction=0.8 --driver-memory 45G --packages "io.archivesunleashed:aut:0.12.1"
./spark-2.1.1-bin-hadoop2.6/bin/spark-shell --conf spark.default.parallelism=64 --driver-memory 45G --packages "io.archivesunleashed:aut:0.12.1"
./spark-2.1.1-bin-hadoop2.6/bin/spark-shell --conf spark.default.parallelism=500 --driver-memory 45G --packages "io.archivesunleashed:aut:0.12.1"
./spark-2.1.1-bin-hadoop2.6/bin/spark-shell --conf spark.memory.offHeap.enabled=true --conf spark.memory.offHeap.size=100G --driver-memory 45G --packages "io.archivesunleashed:aut:0.12.1"
./spark-2.1.1-bin-hadoop2.6/bin/spark-shell --driver-memory 45G --executor-memory 10G --packages "io.archivesunleashed:aut:0.12.1"
./spark-2.1.1-bin-hadoop2.6/bin/spark-shell --driver-memory 45G --executor-memory 45G --packages "io.archivesunleashed:aut:0.12.1"
```

Comment: @Carcigenicate via `--driver-memory` I should have 45GB?

Comment: You need to set `--executor-memory` :)

Comment: @GlennieHellesSindholt Thanks – even when running locally?

Comment: Yes, running locally makes no difference. Spark will still "pretend" that it is running in a distributed environment and create executors to do the work.

Comment: @GlennieHellesSindholt Thanks - am running trials with both driver and executor memory right now.

Comment: @GlennieHellesSindholt no dice on that front. thank you for your help. I will edit my question to include all the commands I have tried.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was ultimately to reduce the number of worker threads.

By default, Spark runs with local[*] which runs the number of threads = cores on the machine, which in this case was 16.

By reducing to local[14] the jobs completed.

Syntax to run:

```
./spark-2.1.1-bin-hadoop2.6/bin/spark-shell --master local[12] --driver-memory 45G --packages "io.archivesunleashed:aut:0.12.1"
```